# Terraform. Getting data from remote-exec

Tags: terraform, proxmox

I have a script that I need help with. I need to get the output value from remote-exec in order to write it to the inventory file.I leave here a part of the code that is needed to understand the problem and why it appeared Thanks in advance for your help

> The container gets a dynamic IP address 
> From PVE you need to get the address of the container

```
resource "proxmox_lxc" "ct_name" {
   ....
        network {
            name = "eth0"
            bridge = "vmbr0"
            ip = "dhcp"
            ip6 = "dhcp"
        }
    
    
      provisioner "remote-exec" {
      inline = [
          "lxc-info -n ${var.ct_vmid} -iH ", # In this place I need help 
       ]
      }  
        connection {
          type = "ssh"
          user = var.pm_admin
          host = var.pm_ip
          private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
          }
    }
    
    resource "local_file" "inventory" {
        filename = "./hosts"
        content     = <<-EOT
        [prx]
        
        [websrv]
        
        [dbsrv]
    
      EOT
    }
```

Comment: Remote provisioners are for modifying the remote server to make it ready to use, rather than for gathering data. I think you'll have a better time with a different solution to this problem, such as having software run in the VM/container on startup and _push_ that data to some shared location where other software can access it, and/or using Ansible dynamic inventory (I'm guessing Ansible because that looks like its syntax).

Comment: A combination of `remote-exec` writing to a file on the remote system and the `file` provisioner to retrieve the file _might_ work, but is not using these features the way they are intended and [provisioners are a last resort](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort).

Comment: Assuming that what you are trying to do here is gather information from the instance for Ansible inventory variables, it would probably be easier to just do this intrinsically in Ansible with fact gathering. Agree with @MartinAtkins comment that is an awkward use case for TF soft prov.